# Django Backend - React Frontend: Trouble Creating User Profiles via POST Request

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

When attempting to create user profiles through a POST request from a React frontend to a Django backend, the user profile creation process isn't functioning as expected. Despite sending the necessary data to the backend, the user profile creation fails, and the expected profile isn't being created for the user.

```
let UserProfileCreation = async (formData, userId) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-profile/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("authToken")}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          user: userId,
          first_name: formData.name,
          last_name: formData.lastname,
          description: formData.txtname,
          phone_number: formData.number,
          // Include image fields if required: profile_picture, banner_picture
        }),
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating profile:", error);
      return false;
    }
  };
```

```
let loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Submitted!");
    let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: e.target.username.value,
        password: e.target.password.value,
      }),
    });
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(jwtDecode(data.access));
    if (response.status === 200) {
      setAuthToken(data);
      setuser(jwtDecode(data.access));
      localStorage.setItem("authToken", JSON.stringify(data));
      const profileExists = await CheckProfile(jwtDecode(data.access).user_id); // Pass the user ID

      if (profileExists) {
        navigate("/");
      } else {
        navigate("/continue-setup");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
```

```
class UserProfileView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = UseProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UseProfileSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="user/profile", null=True, blank=True)
banner_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="user/profile", blank=True, null=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

- Checked Backend Endpoint: Verified that the backend endpoint
- Authentication and Headers: Ensured that the POST request from React includes the necessary headers (Content-Type: application/json and Authorization: Bearer ) for proper authentication.
- Request Payload Validation

Comment: Kindly share the logs that your server may be showing.

Comment: [18/Dec/2023 21:23:05] "POST /user-profile/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2569
Method Not Allowed: /user-profile

Comment: [18/Dec/2023 22:01:23] "POST /user-profile HTTP/1.1" 400 187
Method Not Allowed: /user-profile

Comment: could you share the urls.py? what did you change that one time you got 403 and after that, you got 400?

Comment: Fixed the issue